# Sum41? How About Tongue41?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

I'll admit, okay? I have no tongue.
But that doesn't mean that we are done-
A delicious dessert, or perhaps your manhood;
But don't forget to double it good.
A cold treat with a 'nana
But without the sun-
'cause that would melt it,
Which would be no fun.
And perhaps instead we could mention my dad,
Also two of him, or it could turn bad.

I'm horrendously ugly;
I'm sorry, okay?
You just have to realize
that I was born this way.
Riding on my father's coattails-
Or perhaps I meant my mother?
And maybe not riding at all
but embedding even deeper.

Maybe I can't speak
Like an imaginary electric rat,
But my appearance can still give you a heart attack.
With my streamlined, thin body,
you might think I'm a model,
But if you saw me you'd run me over; full throttle.
Big, fat feet and spaced out eyes-
Honestly, God didn't even try.

> For real, I can't stress how ugly this thing is. Relay this poor creature's existence to all you know. Oh, that's right! Give me a moment... yada yada yada... "who am I?"

Hint 1:

> What do you mean, "Hint 1"? The hint is right there in front of you! Okay, Okay, alligator teeth!

Comment: As the answer's been found- what do you think? Just [his face is ugly](https://53744bf91d44b81762e0-fbbc959d4e21c00b07dbe9c75f9c0b63.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/media/3A/3AB8988D-B603-4965-9CA7-D305CBA762E7/Presentation.Large/Close-up-of-a-Suriname-toad.jpg), but how about [the children](https://53744bf91d44b81762e0-fbbc959d4e21c00b07dbe9c75f9c0b63.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/media/72/721DAE0A-C68C-4C83-82C0-62CE942A2383/Presentation.Large/Suriname-toad-with-young-emerging-from-its-back.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're some sort of

> [Pipidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipidae).  Specifically, a [Pipa pipa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipa_pipa)

---

I'll admit, okay? I have no tongue.

> They're tongueless

But that doesn't mean that we are done-
A delicious dessert, or perhaps your manhood;

> Some pi(e) or...?

But don't forget to double it good.

> 'pi' doubled = 'pipi'

A cold treat with a 'nana
But without the sun-
'cause that would melt it,
Which would be no fun.

> A sundae, minus 'sun' = 'dae'

And perhaps instead we could mention my dad,
Also two of him, or it could turn bad.

> Not sure.  Maybe referring to a [Pipa pipa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipa_pipa) ('Pi' + 'pa', doubled)?

I'm horrendously ugly;
I'm sorry, okay?
You just have to realize
that I was born this way.

> It's ugly.

Riding on my father's coattails-
Or perhaps I meant my mother?
And maybe not riding at all
but embedding even deeper.

> The eggs of some Pipa species are embedded in the mother's back

Maybe I can't speak
Like an imaginary electric rat,

> 'Pipa' is like 'Pika'chu?

But my appearance can still give you a heart attack.

> It's ugly?

With my streamlined, thin body,
you might think I'm a model,

> They have flat bodies with a [lateral line system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_line)

But if you saw me you'd run me over; full throttle.

> It's ugly.

Big, fat feet and spaced out eyes-

> It has those physical qualities

Honestly, God didn't even try.

> It's ugly.

Hint:

> The first letters spell **FROG**, which this is a type of.  Also, it's ugly.

Comment: hagfy, sorry I wasn't paying attention, is your answer ugly? _Edit: Okay, fair point, [yowza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Suriname_toad#/media/File:Surinam_toad_(DFdB).jpg)_

Comment: @iiiidk It seems my edit was the species you were looking for, so I added it to the top.  Thanks for the revolting puzzle!

Comment: And thank you for solving :') Sorry for opening your eyes to such a horrendous monster!

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> Platypus?

I'll admit, okay? I have no tongue.

> This is where I have a problem. From what I can tell, it has a tongue, though I am no expert.

A delicious dessert, or perhaps your manhood;
But don't forget to double it good.

> The plural of platypus is platypi, as in a plate-a-pie, which indeed is a delicious dessert. I'm not sure about the other.

A cold treat with a 'nana
But without the sun-
'cause that would melt it,
Which would be no fun.

> Pie usually topped with ice-cream, or it can be served cold, like pumpkin pie.

And perhaps instead we could mention my dad,
Also two of him, or it could turn bad.

> Platypi have bills like ducks. Ducks are famous for duck-a-la-mod. I'm not sure on the two of him part though.

I'm horrendously ugly;
I'm sorry, okay?
You just have to realize
that I was born this way.

> From it's wikipedia page, "[The first scientists to examine a preserved platypus body (in 1799) judged it a fake, made of several animals sewn together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus)"

Riding on my father's coattails-
Or perhaps I meant my mother?

> They have beaver tails.

And maybe not riding at all
but embedding even deeper.

> Platypi have been growing more popular in pop culture, especially thanks to Phineas and Ferb's pet platypus, Perry.

Maybe I can't speak
Like an imaginary electric rat,

> The noise they make is interesting, and they do look like Pokemon, which the electric rat is referencing.

But my appearance can still give you a heart attack.

> It looks like an abomination.

With my streamlined, thin body,
you might think I'm a model,

> Their body is great for semi-aquatic activities!

But if you saw me you'd run me over; full throttle.

> Honestly. You'd be like, "Kill it with fire, it's so ugly!" No to mention it has poisonous barbs on its feet.

Big, fat feet and spaced out eyes-

> They have webbed feet and empty eyes.

Honestly, God didn't even try.

> There is a joke that says there is proof that God must have a sense of humor, because he created the platypus.

Hint 1:

> Alligator teeth. I don't know if this one is true.

Comment: I LOVE the pie pun (+1)! You've got the rat as well. Alas, you're correct that they have a tongue.

Comment: But it's not the answer?

Comment: Nye sir, but once again I used one of your favorite tricks :) "alligator teeth" refers to something you used in this very post!